# simple app crashing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, crash

I have a very simple window based app, i am simply putting a navigation view controller as window's root view controller and it's crashing. This is the only thing i changed in the template project:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];


    [[self window] setRootViewController:navigationController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

It crashes saying:

```
2011-05-26 20:18:57.194 ZebraSDKTest[5560:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UICustomObject 0x8b3d760> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key navigationController.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dbf5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f13313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00dbf4e1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x00791677 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 135
    4   Foundation                          0x007915e5 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285
    5   UIKit                               0x0020d30c -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 112
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00d358cf -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 239
    7   UIKit                               0x0020bd23 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1041
    8   UIKit                               0x0020dab7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    9   UIKit                               0x0001317a -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 172
    10  UIKit                               0x00013cf4 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 291
    11  UIKit                               0x0001e617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    12  UIKit                           

0x00016abf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
13  UIKit                               0x0001bf2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
14  GraphicsServices                    0x00ff8992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00da0944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00cfdf83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00cfd840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00cfd761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
20  UIKit                               0x000137d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623
21  UIKit                               0x0001fc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
22  ZebraSDKTest                        0x00002549 main + 121
23  ZebraSDKTest                        0x000024c5 start + 53
```

)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have a connection to a former existing UINavigationController IBOutlet in one of your nib files.

Start with MainWindow.xib and check for such a connection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just checked everything, it is hooked up. There's 4 things there, app delegate, files owner, window and first responder. Checked all their outlets manually, reassigned. There's also no exclamation mark in the outlets pane..

Comment: Try to remove the app from the device or simulator.

Comment: No luck. Thanks for trying to help me out though. I uploaded the project here: https://rapidshare.com/files/3683206909/ZebraSDKTest.zip if you have time, maybe you can look at it? Thanks again.

Comment: In the `Xcode` menu, go to `Product` > `Clean`. Once done, build your project and run it.

Comment: I just downloaded and ran your app with no problems at all, so I'm not sure what the problem is.  The code seems to be fine, so is the xib file.  I imagine it is an internal issue with your emulator or xcode.  I would take @Deepak's advice and clean it.  If that doesn't do the trick, quit out of xcode and the simulator, then open it up again to see if that does the trick

Comment: Still didn't work. But I just created a new project and started over again. Don't know why it happened...

Comment: I also faced the same issue .  I jus removed all the outlet connection and recreated IBOutlet ; Its working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem occurring on the simulator only, but on the device it was working fine.

I tried cleaning the project, restarting Xcode, debugging, emptying the simulator data, the whole works.

In the end it was resolved by uninstalling the app from the simulator and reinstalling it. No idea why that worked, but it solved it!